# Revert Django Admin Templates to Default

Tags: django, git

I was attempting to try out a different set of django admin templates (looking for something more mobile) and installed [Django Admin Bootstrapped](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped) as a trial.

I've decided I don't want to use these right now and attempted to perform a `git reset --hard` but while this removed the app from my installed apps the templates are still all messed up.

How do I revert my django admin templates to the original style/structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove any additional apps from `INSTALLED_APPS` and make sure your app/project doesn't have a directory called `admin` under the 'templates` directory.

Also, review `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in your `settings.py` file to make sure there are no paths there that have admin overrides too.